# Is it better using a guard clause or catching the exception?

Tags: c#, java, exception

is it better to prevent exception with a guard clause or catch the exception?
There is a best practice?
Pro and cons of the two methodologies?

For example is better this:

```
try
{ 
    param=myArray[3];
}
catch (IndexOutOfRangeException e)
{
    do something...
}
```

or this:

```
if(myArray.Length < 4)
{
    do something...
}
else
{
    param=myArray[3];
}
```

Thank you all for the answers :)

Comment: If you can avoid the exception, that's better because exceptions have overhead.

Comment: If you are expecting something at index 3,it's an **error** if you don't have it there..it's better to close your app and log that error instead of catching an exception or trying to solve it..

Comment: @Anirudh: What if you're parsing a file which is supposed to be properly formatted, and items will be placed into and fetched from a collection based upon what's in the file?  If the only recovery action one will want in case the file is invalid is to have the `ParseFile` routine throw an exception indicating the file couldn't be loaded, trying various operations and catching any exceptions that occur would seem cleaner than having guard clauses everyplace whose only purpose is to throw an exception if something is wrong.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> is it better to prevent exception with a guard clause or catch the exception?

In the case of "boneheaded" exceptions like index out of range, always the former.

In the case of "exogenous" exceptions, always the latter.

> Pro and cons of the two methodologies?

There are only cons of the latter in the case of boneheaded exceptions. They are:

- Exceptions are *incredibly expensive* compared to tests.
- Exceptions are intended to model *exceptionally rare* control flow situations; if potentially accessing an index out of range is *normal* then don't write an *exception* handler.
- Exceptions are reported as "first chance" exceptions to listeners *even if the exception is handled*. Many systems -- ASP, for example -- listen for first chance exceptions, log all of them, and treat components that produce a lot of them as *buggy*, because *they are*. (I once introduced a deliberate first-chance exception in a common code path in ASP and a day later boy did I hear about it. The buggy-subsystem tests went crazy.)
- There are some exceptions that I call the "boneheaded" exceptions -- null dereference, index out of range, and so on -- that because they are so easy to avoid and indicate failures so obviously dangerous that they should *always* be treated as fatal bugs and *never* handled (unless the "handler" is logging them before shutting down the process.) Don't handle the bug, *eliminate the bug*.

Finally, you should read my article on this subject.

http://ericlippert.com/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/

Comment: I use your post as a guide when coding. I throw _boneheaded_ exceptions using Code Contracts, have `TryX` methods instead of throwing _vexing_ exceptions, and handle all _exogenous_ exceptions.

Comment: Guard clauses may be useful with exogenous exceptions in cases where there's a cheap way to predict with reasonable probability whether an operation will succeed or fail.  For example, if one is going to write a gig of data to one or more files, it may be helpful to check that space exists before starting.  Even if one checks for space beforehand one must still be prepared for the possibility that it might not exist later, but if one can report a problem earlier one should try to do so.

Answer (score 18):

Use a guard clause - catching the exception incurs a high runtime cost, and in general to improve readability you should only use exceptions for error conditions, not for normal control flow

Comment: that is an error condition..if he is expecting something at index 3 it's an error if he doesn't have it there..it's better to close app and log that error..

Comment: @Anirudh It depends on the situation; both *can* be correct.  It depends on whether it's expected that the array might not have that many values or whether the application is completely reliant on the array being at least that large.  That determines whether you should check for it or just let it throw an exception.

Comment: @anirudha I am curious why you keep saying close the app upon this type of exception? The operation may be retryable or not severe enough to warrant shutting the app down. Why not let a top level exception handler log the error so you can go back and eliminate the bug? There are more user friendly ways to make the developer aware of the bug than killing the program.

Answer (score 5):

Guard clause. You never want to use `try`/`catch` for control flow. Catching exceptions is expensive and should be avoided as much as you can.

Comment: More accurately, it's preferable to avoid try/catch for *normal* control flow.

Answer (score 4):

In cases where the Exception can be prevented, prevent it. Always.

Catching and handling Exceptions is expensive and should never be used for normal control flow. A guard is cheap and easy.

Comment: Doesn't it depend what the guard is?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko - You'd be hard pressed to find a case where a guard is more costly than the Exception handling.

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to the `a guard is cheap` part.

Comment: I disagree with the "always".  It's usually best, but not always.  For example, if you'd need to perform a network request in order to determine if a subsequent network request would succeed it can be *way* more expensive than just performing the second network request and catching an exception if it was invalid.  (I.e. if you want to pull a file from an FTP server you may not want to check if it exists; just let your get request fail if it doesn't.)

Comment: @Servy: But there is *no* network request you can perform that will tell you *if a subsequent request will succeed*. Someone could unplug the network cable after the first request.  A network exception is an "exogenous" exception; it is out of your control entirely. That's completely different than a "boneheaded" exception like index out of range, where you can know with 100% accuracy whether the exception will be thrown or not.

Comment: @EricLippert It's true you can't *know* whether the subsequent request will succeed or fail based on an initial request, but if it's expected that the file may not exist then you're ensuring that the subsequent will only throw an exception in exceptional circumstances, and that none of the exceptions will represent normal control flow.  In just the same way verifying the length of the array won't ensure that there is never an exception thrown when accessing the array, it just ensures any exceptions that could be thrown are truly exceptional, not normal control flow (i.e. ThreadAbortException).

Comment: @Servy: I agree with you.  In some cases testing for whether an exceptional condition is likely may be cheaper than attempting an operation which ends up failing.  In other cases, it may be better to just try the operation and cope with the failure (especially if a failed attempt will have no side effects and will be no more expensive than an advance test).  Arguably, the exceptions in the latter case might be "vexing" exceptions [i.e. the API perhaps should have provided a "TryDoSomething" method to allow the expected condition to be handled without throwing an exception].

Comment: *In cases where .. Always* says that if other cases are also included, then it would be *in most cases* (usually?). That is, except cases those are excluded by the statement, then always. And so agree.