# Wrapping all method body in try block vs wrapping only particular instructions

Tags: coding-style, try-catch

Looking at the code I recently wrote made me wonder:

```java
public void process(Deque<OperandToken> stack, EvaluationConfig context) {
    OperandToken a;
    OperandToken b;
    try {
        b = stack.pop();
        a = stack.pop();
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        throw new EvaluationException("Syntax error: not enough operands");
    }

    if (!a.isValueTypeOf(Number.class) || !b.isValueTypeOf(Number.class)) {
        throw new EvaluationException("Syntax error...");
    }

    // more actions on a and b and finally stack.push(result)
}
```

Same but with catch in the end:

```java
public void process(Deque<OperandToken> stack, EvaluationConfig context) {
    try {
        OperandToken b = stack.pop();
        OperandToken a = stack.pop();

        if (!a.isValueTypeOf(Number.class) || !b.isValueTypeOf(Number.class)) {
            throw new EvaluationException("Syntax error...");
        }

        // more actions on a and b and finally stack.push(result)

    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        throw new EvaluationException("Syntax error: not enough operands");
    }
}
```

Is there any rule about preferred method, or some arguments (e.g. performance) that the first / the second style should be used? In both cases `NoSuchElementException` is the only exception that can appear, but the question is also valid for cases when there are multiple exceptions that can be thrown on different lines.

Comment: In this case I'd actually remove the trycatcth altogether and replace it with a precondition if(stack.size() < 2) { throw new ... }. About your question I prefer the first one because: 1. The less indentation I see in a method the better it is. 2. It's clear to the reader that only those two lines can cause the exception to occur.

Comment: @FabioMarcolini Also thought about indentiation and making it obvious that only those lines throw an exception. On the other hand, no need to separate declaration from assignment.
With regard to removing try/catch - well why? one check less, and try/catch is said not to have impact on performance.

Comment: trycatch is really costly when the exception is actually thrown. The cost of an if in this case is really low I mean to make it matter you would need the if in a tight loop and even there the performance bottleneck would be in the "more actions on a and b" part.

Comment: Anyway I asked a [question about using if against trycatch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16484646/is-it-better-using-a-guard-clause-or-catching-the-exception) some times ago and the mythical Eric Lippert responded pointing to a [post in his blog](http://ericlippert.com/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/)

Comment: @FabioMarcolini Interesting read, however now it seems to me that I'm throwing a 'vexing' exception there :) FYI I am writing an expression language evaluator (using RPN) for my needs, and that is the body of some OperatorToken that does a binary operation over two head elements. The exception will only then be thrown if expression syntax was incorrect (e.g. "1+2/*3"), but the expressions are to be hardcoded in tests rather than expected from input to be 'any old thing'.